# Inversion: Find the transformation of a circle

Tags: geometry, inversive-geometry

> To what point or curve does the inversion $I_{0,5}$ transform the
> circle centered at $(15,0)$ with radius $13?$

*$I_{0,5}$ means inverting on a circle of radius $5$ centered at $(0,0).$*

I was looking at this question and answer as reference:

> The same question but with $I_{0,4}$ and the circle centered at $(0,2)$ with a radius of $1.$

*If $q$ is the circle centered at $(0, 2)$ with a radius of $1$ unit, then $I_{0,4}$  is a circle bisected by the $y$-axis. The intersects of $q$ with the $y$-axis are $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 3)$ and these are transformed by to the points $(0, 16/3)$ and $(0, 16).$*

So using the idea and applying it to my question:

Then this circle is bisected by the $x$-axis where the intersects are $(2,0)$ and $(28,0)$ but now I'm having a hard time finding out the transformations.

I know by definition in the unit circle:

the transformation occurs like this:

$t: (x,y) \to (\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$

but this is for radius $1.$

So if anyone can explain how to get the transformation points or in the question I was looking as reference, how did they get $(0,16/3)$ and $(0,16),$ that would help a lot!

Comment: Where is your reference question?

Comment: You could translate the point $(15,0)$ to the origin, then scale the entire space by $1/13$, do the unit circle inversion and then undo the two previous transformations.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I'll bold it.

Comment: what is $I_{0.5}?$

Comment: @abel, the book writes it like that but i'm guessing it is an inversion by 1/2

Comment: @MichaelBurr So my new point would be (15/13,0) but how do you undo then? Multiply by 13 afterwards?

Comment: how are you going to do this problem if you don't know exactly what $I_{0.5}$ means?

Comment: @abel thats why I'm obviously asking for help. If i knew what it meant, then I would be able to understand the reference problem and this question wouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: It is not 0.5 but 0,5 with the center being 0 and radius=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am going to assume that $$I_{0, 5} \text{ means inverting on a circle of radius $5$ centered at $(0,0).$  }$$
the circle centered at $$(15, 0) \text{ and radius $ 13$ has $x$- intercepts at } A = (2,0), B = (28,0)$$ let the images of $A,B$ are $A'=(a', 0), B'=(b', 0)$ respectively. then $$a' \times 2 = 5^2, b' \times 28 = 25 \to a' = \frac{25} 2, b' = \frac{25}{28}$$ the image of the circle cecentered at $(15, 0)$ and of radius $ 13$ is a circle centered at $(\frac{375}{56},0)$ and of radius $\frac{325}{56}.$

Comment: I understand everything until you got up to the last sentence where you described the image of the circle. I'm guessing you meant (375/56,0) for the center but how did you get that number for center and radius?

Comment: @kero, that was a typo. is fixed now. the image of a circle is again a circle or  a line. line if the circle passes through the center of the mirror circle. i took the center as the mid point of $a', b'$ and the radius $\frac 12(a' - b').$

Comment: i understand. thanks for being in depth!

Comment: @kero, you are welcome. enjoy the geometry of inversion. it leads to deeper mathematics like hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: that's the next topic on the list, that we shall be studying.